# Unable to create PMMLPipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, sklearn-pandas, jupyterhub, pmml

I am currently trying to export a logistic regression model (built in my Jupyterhub on a Python3 kernel) into a PMML format.

My dataframe is called balanced_data
The predictors for the model are:

> type, amount, oldbalanceOrig, newbalanceOrig, oldbalanceDest

While the target variable is:

> isFraud

I tried using the following syntax to achieve my PMML file:

```
pipeline = PMMLPipeline("mapper", DataFrameMapper([(balanced_data.type, None), 
                                               (balanced_data.amount, None), 
                                               (balanced_data.oldbalanceOrig, None), 
                                               (balanced_data.newbalanceOrig, None),
                                               (balanced_data.oldbalanceDest, None), 
                                               [(balanced_data.isFraud, None)]]),
                    ("classifier", skl.LogisticRegression(penalty="l2",
                                                          dual=False,
                                                          tol=0.0001,
                                                          C=1.0,
                                                          fit_intercept=True,
                                                          intercept_scaling=1, 
                                                          random_state=12345, 
                                                          solver="lbfgs",
                                                          max_iter=100,
                                                          multi_class="ovr", 
                                                          verbose=0, 
                                                          warm_start=False,
                                                          n_jobs=-1)
                     )
                   )
```

But I am encountering the following error.

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

I have never used sklearn2pmml & DataFrameMapper before. Could anyone please advise what went wrong and how to resolve this error?

---

### EDIT:

I have removed the pair of square brackets to obtain the following but I still encounter the same error.

```
pipeline = PMMLPipeline("mapper", DataFrameMapper([(balanced_data.type, None), 
                                               (balanced_data.amount, None), 
                                               (balanced_data.oldbalanceOrig, None), 
                                               (balanced_data.newbalanceOrig, None),
                                               (balanced_data.oldbalanceDest, None), 
                                               (balanced_data.isFraud, None)]),
                    ("classifier", skl.LogisticRegression(penalty="l2",
                                                          dual=False,
                                                          tol=0.0001,
                                                          C=1.0,
                                                          fit_intercept=True,
                                                          intercept_scaling=1, 
                                                          random_state=12345, 
                                                          solver="lbfgs",
                                                          max_iter=100,
                                                          multi_class="ovr", 
                                                          verbose=0, 
                                                          warm_start=False,
                                                          n_jobs=-1)
                     )
                   )
```

Comment: I have solved the problem, will highlight out what I'm missing in my syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I will highlight whatever I'm missing in my syntax and upload an
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxBGc.png) to show the highlights.
I have also added the code snippet for easier copy pasta.

```
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("mapper", DataFrameMapper([
                                                 (["balanced_data.type",
                                                   "balanced_data.amount",
                                                   "balanced_data.oldbalanceOrig",
                                                   "balanced_data.newbalanceOrig",
                                                   "balanced_data.oldbalanceDest"], None)
                                               ])
                     ),
                     ("classifier", model
                     )
                   ])
```

---

### EDIT:

So I encountered an error when trying to fit the training data into the pipeline. I resolved this issue by using the following syntax for my DataFrameMapper instead.

```
DataFrameMapper([
                 (["type",
                   "amount",
                   "oldbalanceOrig",
                   "newbalanceOrig",
                   "oldbalanceDest"], None)
               ])
```

Learnt that DataFrameMapper was to only build the "table" structure and not the table itself.